# Unable to launch google map link in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, google-api, maps

Using the link got from google Maps API -> **https://maps.google.com/?cid=10698500154823482329** is not working/opening in the app. But when I try to open the same place URL(but it's a website link) **https://g.page/jessidrivingschool?share** is working fine when using the launch **url_launcher** library in flutter.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://maps.google.com/?cid=10698500154823482329
```

Can you please help with this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be caused by the update to how package visibility is handled in Android 11.  You now need to list the third party apps that you interact with. See here for more info https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

If this is the case, then it can be fixed by adding this to your manifest

```
<queries>
      <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
      <intent>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
      </intent>
  </queries>
```